# Need help taking the results of a SQL select statment and outting them into a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SELECT [Name], COUNT([Name]) AS Count FROM [DelegationTracker] WHERE [Date] = @Date GROUP BY [Name], Connection);Conn);
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SELECT @User_Tested FROM WHMIS_User_Tests;, Connct);
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@Name, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = HttpContext.Current.Session[Name].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@Date, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Date;MMDDYYYY
             cmd.Parameters.Add(@Grade, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = null;
            Connection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    test = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    test2 = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                }

            }

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            Adapter.Fill(dt);
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Adapter.Fill(ds);
            MainGridView.DataSource = dt;
            MainGridView.DataSource = ds;
            MainGridView.DataBind();
            Connection.Close();
            return true;
}
```

the gridview does not display im assuming its because it has no data and the DataTable returns the 1 record in the SQL table but does not display it (within the gridview) the dataset as far as i can tell returns nothing

the reason i have so many adapters and dataset and datatable is that i was testing to see what worked but none have produced any results...

Comment: Have you checked that the DataTable and the DataSet are not empty?

Comment: Do you have an actual question? What specific problems are you encountering with filling the grid view?

Comment: the gridview does not display im assuming its because it has no data and the DataTable returns the 1 record in the SQL table but does not display it (within the gridview) the dataset as far as i can tell returns nothing

Comment: You have set the gridview data source twice and second time to the "ds". That would be overwriting the "ds" as gridview's datasource, instead of "dt". This may be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure whats going on in your sample code. It almost looks like you took two different methods and shuffled them together. Here's a simple method or loading a DataGrid using one of the two SQL queries you provided.

```
private void LoadDataGrid(DataGrid dataGrid, DateTime date, string connectionString) 
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) 
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter {
                ParameterName = "@Date",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime,
                Value = date
            });
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Name], " +
                              "       COUNT([Name]) AS Count " +
                              "FROM   [DelegationTracker] " +
                              "WHERE  [Date] = @Date " +
                              "GROUP  BY [Name]";

            conn.Open();
            try 
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
                {
                    dataGrid.DataSource = reader;
                    dataGrid.DataBind();
                }
            }
            finally 
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```